# Verifying multiple words only found in a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have some data

```
data = ['vancouver', 'paris', 'montreal']
string = 'montrealvancouverparis'
```

I am checking only those strings in the data found in a string only. I am intending to find the words of data one by one in the string variable. So, that in the end, it will give me the empty string meaning all words of data found in the string variable.
So far, I have tried this but no luck

```
found_words = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i] in string:
        found_words.append(string.replace(data[i], ''))
found_words
```

```
Output: ['montrealparis', 'montrealvancouver', 'vancouverparis']
```

```
Desired Output: string = ''
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by authenticating? Can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: What are `var` and `data_new`? Also, please provide a better example. All the elements in `data` are in `string` so I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are a mess – What is `var` ? Looks like it should be `data[i]` instead of 'var[i]'. And `data_new` is not defined either. This should work:

```
data = ['vancouver', 'paris', 'montreal']
string = 'montrealvancouverparis'
buffer = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i] in string:
        buffer.append(string.replace(data[i], ''))
print(buffer)

['montrealparis', 'montrealvancouver', 'vancouverparis']
```

This give you the output you stated. If you instead want to end up with the **empty string**, you need to update the string you are searching each time to remove the data that was found previously:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i] in string:
        string = string.replace(data[i], '')
print(f"Final String: '{string}'")

Final String: ''
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can just use list comprehension:

```
>>> [word for word in data if word in string]
['vancouver', 'paris', 'montreal']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = ['vancouver', 'paris', 'montreal']
string = 'montrealvancouverparis'
found_words = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i] in string:
        found_words.append(data[i])
 found_words
```